# input buttons and 508 compliance: do they really need labels?

Tags: section508

Does a button with a value really need a matching label tag in order to be 508 compliant?

Say I have:

```
<label for="search_box" class="hideme">search query</label>
<input type="text" id="search_box">
<input type="button" id="search" value="Search">
```

The web accessibility testing software is flagging it since it has an id but no matching label? Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<label>` is not needed for `<input type="button">`, you need to provide a value attribute. If the button is using an image versus text, you need to provide an alt to be compliant.

```
<input type="button" src="....jpg" alt="Search" id="...">
```

Comment: hmmm... that's what I thought, getting flags about it. Maybe the person testing it wasn't quite sure... Also wondering whether labels are needed for inputs that have been given a title="" tag?

Comment: Please specify what testing software you are using. I can give advice after that. Do not use the title tag. The title is not supported in all browsers for people using the keyboard. Some AT can output the title attribute if the person enables it. Please see [this blog post](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2010/11/using-the-html-title-attribute/)

Comment: We are just using the Web Accessibility Toolbar, as it appears to be the tool used by those assessing our software. Thanks for the article, it's an interesting read. I was unaware that some screen readers didn't re-map to the title attribute upon encountering missing labels. I've actually been given the advice to use a label with a display:none css class as a possible solution. The situation I wonder about is like following. Date input layout in a constrained space: <input id="from"><label for="to">to</label><input id="to"> How would you go about adding accessibility to the "from" input?

Comment: Are you using the IE, Firefox or Opera one? Re @Title: Yes, title is often thought as a good fall back, but it isn't really. Re Display:none: Some AT ignore that rule, it is best to shove it off-screen. position:relative;left:-9999em; is the common way. I think you need to open a new question for the date... I can't quite see what you're asking.

Comment: Hmmm... I see, is the negative margin the best way to go about this? Btw, went and made that separate question out of it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588625/508-compliance-title-attribute-vs-a-hidden-absolutely-positioned-label

Comment: I will reply to your new question