# 508 Compliance title attribute vs a hidden absolutely positioned label

Tags: css, section508

Is the title attribute ok to use for accesibility when it comes to 508 compliance?

For example:

```
<style>
    #date_box{width:250px; border:2px solid #AAA;}
    input{width:100px;}
</style>

<div id="date_box">
    <input title="to" type="text" id="to" name="to" />
    <label for="from">from</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
</div>
```

Or is it best to do a hidden label with an absolute position and a negative margin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a visual label on a control is redundant it is OK to use a title attribute. The [accessible name calculation](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-api-map/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#calc) for form controls includes the title attribute content, so it is now it has been in the past and will continue to be a robust method to provide an accessible name for a control in the limted circimstances where a visible label is not required. There is a [WCAG 2.0 technqiue](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H65.html) that covers this. This article provides test results and discussion on this technique: [Title Attributes as Form Control Labels](http://www.accessibleculture.org/articles/2010/10/title-attributes-as-form-control-labels/)

Comment: Cool, and thank  you for the references. You don't happen to know off the top of your head if screen readers follow these calculations?

Comment: Hi Serhiy, Its not for the acreen readers to follow its for the browsers to follow, they do the mapping from HTML to the accessibility APIs which is then available to the screen reader software. All browsers that implement accessibility support use the accessible name calculation algorithm (Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari(mac). The browsers that do not support accessibility currently (such as Opera, safari on windows) are not usable by screen reader users, so you don't have to worry about those.

Answer (score 2):

The [Section 508 rule](http://www.section508.gov/index.cfm?fuseAction=stdsdoc#Web) about forms is rather abstract: “(n) When electronic forms are designed to be completed on-line, the form shall allow people using assistive technology to access the information, field elements, and functionality required for completion and submission of the form, including all directions and cues.”

So the questions here are: If you use a form field without a label, can you ensure that any assistive software gives the user access to the text that is logically a label but placed e.g. into the field as default content and/or in a `title` attribute? And if you use a label but hide it with CSS, is it sure that any assistive software can still make it available to the user.

I don’t think that anyone can guarantee that for all current and future programs, so it is clearly safest to use a normal label and normal `label` markup.

Comment: I can wholeheartedly agree about using normal labels and mark-up. Though at the moment I'm in the process of making a legacy app more accessible, and lots of UI re-design as a result is not a path we want to rush down. So I'm just looking for ways to add accessibility with minimal UI changes.